# What is the best way to authenticate with Facebook in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, restify

I'm building a chrome extension that is going to interact with a Node.js/Restify web service that I am also building. I used passport.js to make a couple API endpoints for users to hit and be authenticated with Facebook. However, once I got the chrome extension piece running, I realized that there were all kinds of CORS problems when trying to request my Facebook auth endpoints via ajax.

After looking into the problem online, it looks like most people do Facebook auth all on client side. Now I'm thinking, maybe I rewrite the extension to use client-side Facebook auth and keep everything else (non-Facebook) going through my Restify API.

My Facebook auth endpoints look like this:

```
server.get('/facebook_login/callback', auth.authenticate({
  failureRedirect: '/error',
  scope: [
    auth.fbPermissions.email,
    auth.fbPermissions.publicProfile
  ]
}), function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/', next);
});

server.get('/facebook_login', auth.authenticate({
  failureRedirect: '/error',
  scope: [
    auth.fbPermissions.email,
    auth.fbPermissions.publicProfile
  ]
}));
```

And the only JavaScript code in the extension is this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.open("http://localhost:8080/facebook_login");
});
```

If anyone has gotten either of these methods working, let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _"I realized that there were all kinds of CORS problems"_ You need to clarify what you mean by that. CORS is usually a non-issue for extensions. Also, check out `chrome.identity`.

Comment: @Xan after changing my code back to reproduce the CORS errors I realized I didn't get them anymore as long as I opened the login urls in a new window. Also, `chrome.identity` looks useful so thank you for that advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by opening my `facebook_login` page in a new window. Looks like I'll stick with server-side Facebook login for now.

Comment: Wise: client-side login has easier to extract API keys.